# VPN interfering with firewall rule

Tags: linux, vpn, firewall

I've opened the Transmission (torrent client) port through the firewall. When the VPN is OFF, the port shows **open**. When VPN is ON, the port shows **closed**. Why is that?

Is it because the network interface changes from wlp1s0 to tun0 when VPN is ON? How to make it effective for tun0 too?

Running Fedora 26 Workstation.

Comment: well, when you are connected to a VPN, you are no longer routing from your home router, you are routing through the VPN's gateway. So if you are using a VPN in China, your traffic will route through China. As that is the whole point of using a VPN for anonymity. Or are you referring to your local firewall on the PC itself?

Comment: wlp1s0... gotta love that. In any case, use firewall rules for tun0 as well as for wlp1s0 if you need to control this traffic.

Comment: I use port forwarding from ISP modem to router, router to computers. I've already found the firewall-cmd option for adding an interface to a firewall zone with the Transmission rules. I reloaded, restarted the computer. But still nothing. Port closed through interface tun0. I need someone who can walk me through Fedora's firewall config, if that is the problem.